# CSS HTML organize 5 images - cross-browser compatible

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I've got 5 images I'd like to organize in an ASP.NET MVC view. So what I need is an HTML+CSS solution (I prefer not to use jQuery for this, for maximal compatibility).

I want to organize the images like so:

```
  Image1           Image2

  Image3           Image4

           Image5
```

At first I tried using tables, with the HTML being:

```
<div class="table1">
    <table border=1>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
              <img class="mainArticleImage" src="../../images/fixedImages/dr_teman_Articles_Body.Contouring.jpg" />
          </td>
          <td>
          <p class="ImageCenterContainer">
              <img class="mainArticleImage" src="../../images/fixedImages/dr_teman_Articles_Breast.jpg" />
          </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>            
    </div>                    
    <div class="table2">
    <table border=1>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
          <p class="ImageCenterContainer">
              <img class="mainArticleImage" src="../../images/fixedImages/dr_teman_Articles_Skin.jpg" />
          </p>
          </td>
          <td>
          <p class="ImageCenterContainer">
              <img class="mainArticleImage" src="../../images/fixedImages/Dr_teman_Articles_Face.jpg" />
          </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>            
    </div>
    <div class="table3">
    <table border=5>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
          <p class="ImageCenterContainer">
              <img class="mainArticleImage" alt="" src="../../images/fixedImages/Dr_teman_Articles_Face.jpg" />
          </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>            
</div>
```

and the css part:

```
.mainArticleImage {    
    height: 95px;
    width: 120px;
}
.ImageCenterContainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

but that doesn't work on IE.

[This approach](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support#) also didn't work too well either.

What is the best, simplest, **cross-browser** way to carry out what would seem to be an easy task?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Describe what actually happens.

Comment: It works fine in Chrome, but in IE the images don't align to the center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/um6d7/

Comment: also - works great in chrome, but doesn't in IE (all the images aren't getting resized, so you get a column of huge pictures)

Comment: Huh.  It works exactly as I expected in my ie.  Is it possible your ie isn't working correctly?  Which version of ie are you using?

Answer (score 0):

@[Brian Flanagan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/450941/brian-flanagan)
(this reply was too long for a comment)

I'm using IE8, but this solution should work for older IE versions as well. Shouldn't it to be fairly simple to organize 5 pictures on a screen? :-P

I should also mention that I didn't copy and paste your solution "as is", since I didn't want my css to refer to general tags such as `img` and `div`, but the changes are meaningless in terms of logic. The actual code I used:

HTML:

```
<div id="imagesContainer">
   <img class="articleImage" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Ocellaris_clownfish.JPG" />
   <img class="articleImage" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Ocellaris_clownfish.JPG" />
   <img class="articleImage" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Ocellaris_clownfish.JPG" />
   <img class="articleImage" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Ocellaris_clownfish.JPG" />
   <img class="articleImage middle" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Ocellaris_clownfish.JPG"/>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#imagesContainer {width:550px; overflow:hidden;}
.articleImage {width:180px; float:left; display:inline; margin:15px;}
.middle {margin:15px 90px;}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, I'm really starting to think there's something up with your ie8.  I pasted your code into a new jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/MQGEe/) and fired up in ie8, 7, and 6.  All rendered exactly the same on my machine.

Comment: I apologize on behalf of Microsoft. My explorer needed me to close it and reopen it to display changes in code. That or CTRL+F5.

In the end I changed the direction of the look, but thank you. Along the way I think I became better equipped for handling IE/everyone-else browser compatibility.

Thank you!